# Writing Custom methods in Java DSL for apache camel routes

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

Can i write my own Processor Definition methods in Camel and use that in my route as below ?

```
from(uri)
.to("http://host:port/testData")
.**setTimeOut(long milliseconds)**
```

from is implemented in RouteDefinition and
to is implemented in ProcessorDefinition. Like that if i want to implement setTimeOut method and use it in java DSL, how can i do that?

PS : I don't want to pass the timeOut as a Httpclient query parameter to HttpUri.

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot do this.

The methods / eips you can use form the Java DSL is fixed. To extend this requires to extend the `RouteBuilder` which allows to add new methods to new starting methods. You cannot add a `setTimeOut` that can work together with `to`, etc.

You would need to add the code to camel-core, and recompile it, which is not recommended.

However you can implement a processor, and then name it setTimeout, and then use the .process

```
Processor setTimeout = new MySetTimeout(1000);

from
  .to
  .process(setTimeout);
```

And then use it as a processor from the `.process` method.